# How can I draw a circle with the arc-method?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a basic paint-program in javascript.

I've added tools for rectangle, line and freehand drawing. Now I need to add a tool for drawing a circle. I found the code for drawing a circle, but I don't know how to implement and change it fit the code I already have.

The code for drawing the line-tool looks like this

```
  tools.line = function () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;

    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
      tool.started = true;
      tool.x0 = ev._x;
      tool.y0 = ev._y;
    };

    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
      if (!tool.started) {
        return;
      }

context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(tool.x0, tool.y0);
      context.lineTo(ev._x,   ev._y);
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();
    };

    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        tool.mousemove(ev);
        tool.started = false;
        img_update();
      }
    };
  };
```

I have tried to make a tool that draws a circle using the arc-method based on this code:

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc(X, Y, R, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.lineWidth = 3;
context.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
context.stroke();
```

I tried to do something like this. Maybe needless to say, with no working result at all..

```
  tools.circle = function () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;

    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
      tool.started = true;
      tool.x0 = ev._x;
      tool.y0 = ev._y;
    };

    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
      if (!tool.started) {
        return;
      }

context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var x = (mouse.x + start_mouse.x) / 2;
    var y = (mouse.y + start_mouse.y) / 2;

    var radius = Math.max(
        Math.abs(mouse.x - start_mouse.x),
        Math.abs(mouse.y - start_mouse.y)
    ) / 2;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();

};

    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        tool.mousemove(ev);
        tool.started = false;
        img_update();
      }
    };
  };
```

The entire code can be seen here [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/yh7yhfJ4)

Comment: Depends on how you want to draw it, by center + radius or by 2 corners of surrounding square.. First one is simpler: you need 2 clicks for that, the first will be for the center (event coordinates for `X` and `Y`) and the second for the radius (`√(deltaX² + deltaY²)` will give you the radius, for `R`). You can keep last parameters as they are for a full circle. But if you want a preview, that's another story..

Comment: Thank you! I guess clicking in one «corner», and then drag the circle from that point would be the most intuitive for the user?

Comment: But then what if the user drags more horizontally than vertically? An ellipse?

Comment: Well, I need a tool for an ellipse as well. So any advice will help.

Comment: There are quite a few variables in your code which are nowhere defined. Can you provide code that is self-consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like: https://jsfiddle.net/byfwuhmj/

The difference is:

```
var radius = Math.max(
    Math.abs(mouse.x - start_mouse.x),
    Math.abs(mouse.y - start_mouse.y)
) / 2;

var x = Math.min(mouse.x, start_mouse.x) + radius;
var y = Math.min(mouse.y, start_mouse.y) + radius;
```

By calculating the radius first, then adding it to the minimum of the two mouse coordinates, the circle stays within the bounding box you would expect from the way most graphics programs work.

The reason it didn't work that way before is that a circle has a square bounding box, because its width and height are the same, but the bounding box created by the two mouse coordinates may not be square.

Comment: This is very nice. Is there a way to make each circle stay on the canvas? And even though your jsfiddle is working nice, the circles won't show within the program I'm trying to make. Any suggestions? [jsbin-version of the file](https://jsbin.com/vasivug/edit?html,output)

Comment: It looks like your code requires you to use tool.x0 tool.y0 instead of start_mouse and ev._x and ev._y instead of mouse